# On click function "div" is not apending

Tags: jquery, html, click, append

I am working with searching string from database and selected string appending to the text box

I can get the search results from database and i can append the result below the textbox.

But  my problem is onclick of particular result I can't get the "id" of appended result

My code looks like this..

```
<span id="new">
    <input id="addSearch" type="text" width="50px"/>
</span>

<div id="append" style="margin-top: -11px;width: 149px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){      
  $("#addSearch").keyup(function() {    
    var v = $('#addSearch').val();
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/api/getresult/?q='+v, function(data){
      $('#append').html('');
        $.each(data, function (key,value){
           $('<div  id='+value["id"]+' class="searchResult">  
                   '+value["name"]+' 
                 </div>').appendTo($('#append'));
         });
     });    
  });    
});
$('.searchResult').click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key up method is correct, you just need to modify the click event like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.searchResult', function(e) {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});​
```

Comment: Note that you can limit the scope of the event handler by binding it to `$('#append')` instead of `$(document)`.

Answer (score 1):

As Adarsh Raj noted, you are not binding the `click` handler on the `.searchResult` elements you append in the AJAX callback. jQuery collections are not "live" and as such, the event handler is directly bound on the *matching DOM elements at the time of the call*.

However, instead of manually binding the handler to each inserted element, you should use a [delegated event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) on a parent element:

```
$('#append').on('click', '.searchResult', function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

This requires that the `#append` element is in the DOM at the time of the call, but any `.searchResult` elements inserted later will be able to trigger the event handler through event propagation. Another advantage is that there is only one event handler handling the click event for *all* `.searchResult` elements, instead of having an event handler for each individual element.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var a = $('<div  id='+value["id"]+' class="searchResult"> '+value["name"]+' </div>');
$('#append').append(a);

instead of your approach below
var a = $('<div  id='+value["id"]+' class="searchResult">  
                       '+value["name"]+' </div>').appendTo($('#append'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need the `var a`

`$(stuff).appendTo(selector)` is fine.

Though that is not the solution, but one observation.

So assuming your response from the back end gives a JSON like so:
    `{
      id: 123,
      name: "name"
    }`

Your iteration in the function 
`$.each(data, function(k,v) {`

`v` itself has the desired values. `value["id"]` is wrong and tries to access the property `id` of the key. So you don't need the iteration over the JSON, you can simply access its properties, if you know what they are.

Try this:

`$('<div id=' + data["id"] + 'class="searchResult">' + data["name"] + ...`

Comment: @abhi try the solution above. Don't iterate, just use `data`. If your JSON structure is something else, you might have to share that, so that I can provide an answer.

Comment: It'd help if we had a sample of the produced JSON. However, I believe he intends it to be an array of `{key:..., value:...}` pairs, so iterating makes sense.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens, I am sure. Hence I'm asking for the sample JSON. Without that, any answer, even mine would be futile :-)

Comment: @Arindam i am getting json result as  [{"id":"1","name":"new_challenge1 by abhi"},{"id":"2","name":"challenge2 by abhi"}]

Answer (score 0):

your are trying to bind the click function before the element came to dom. So do bind the event inside your loop

```
$(function(){      
  $("#addSearch").keyup(function() {    
    var v = $('#addSearch').val();
   $.getJSON('http://localhost/api/getresult/?q='+v, function(data){
     $('#append').html('');
      $.each(data, function (key,value){
         $('<div  id='+value["id"]+' class="searchResult">  
               '+value["name"]+' 
             </div>').appendTo($('#append'));

          bindClick();
       });
   });    
});    
});
function bindClick(){
    $('.searchResult').click(function(){
      alert($(this).attr("id"));
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

$('.searchResult').live('click',  function() {

```
alert($(this).attr("id"));
```

});

Comment: @abhi: Go through this before using `live`. [on-vs-live-review](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/on-vs-live-review/)

Comment: jQuery v.1.7 onwards the `.live()` method is apparently deprecated.

Comment: `.live()` and `.delegate()` have been superseded by `on()`. Their usage is discouraged for new code.